# Why rendering is delayed for >5 seconds?

Tags: reactjs, performance

I have the following React component, it's part of complex system (Redux, Material UI, and 50+ more dependencies)

```
render() {
  console.log("Rendering")
  <div>My Text</div>
}
```

The problem is, the delay between `Rendering` is printed to console and `My Text` is rendered to browser is >5 seconds.

I have checked that no `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `false` in its parent components.

Update: it seems React aggregate and postpone the rendering. But still not sure why

What might be the possible root causes?

Comment: Many things can cause this, from other components blocking its render, your network or anything else, I think you have to provide way more code than this, if someone can tell you from this, he would have to be magician.

Comment: This is the actual code. Unfortunately I find it difficult to explain the whole architecture without making the question too long. There are too many possible related parts. If you could suggest some part to check, I can update the question with explanation/code on that part.

Comment: Well look at every component which lead to this one, which means start at root and then slowly work your way down, other than that, you would have to provide more code, and yes question would be long, but this isnt simple question.

Comment: @PahleviFikriAuliya what is your system configuration?

Comment: It's part of e-commerce system, with Redux, React, MaterialUI, and 50+ more dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried taking a performance timeline and checking what is happening during these 5 seconds? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, we can't really help you.
A simple render like this should render immediately.
You are talking about a complex system, try to explain it

Comment: why did you post this as an answer Joan?

Comment: Because i don't have 50 reputation so i'm not able to comment his question :/

Comment: i understand. but you can earn 50 reputation by answering to proper questions Joan. i appreciate your spirit :)

Comment: Trying to do it actually ;)

Comment: All the best Joan :)